# Static vs. Dynamic binding - what's the difference?

Tags: networking, binding, client-server, terminology

Right now, I am learning about networked systems, and the issue of "binding" came up that was never really covered in our course notes, other than the fact that a client can know which mailbox to send a remote procedure call to at either compile time (static) or runtime (dynamic). And I'm not sure how this is related, but apparently static binding corresponds to C, while dynamic binding corresponds to Lisp and Remote procedure calls...

So I was basically wondering what "binding" is and how it relates to remote procedure calls across networks. My friends told me it's used in compilers too, but I wouldn't know much about that either. Any input is appreciated

Comment: This would probably be easier to explain if you have a specific statement or paragraph from a text that didn't make sense to you.

Comment: Covering network-based RPC systems and compiler internals in one question is definitely "big" :) someone might put a fair amount of time showing how Ruby is very dynamic, how C is static, and how to provide some dynamic-binding properties in C, but if you're just curious about a configuration option in an RPC library, it might not actually demystify anything for you. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is not related to networks.

"binding" in this context means the function that will eventually be called. In C, it is determined at compilation (link) time once and for all, and cannot change once the program is started, whereas in Lisp, the function being called is dynamically looked up each time.